# How to specify custom Sass directory with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, path, sass

Instead of serving my Sass files from the default 'views' directory I'd like to change this to `/assets/sass`

The following attempts are in my main ruby root file in the app:

Attempt 1:

```
set :sass, Proc.new { File.join(root, "assets/sass") }

get '/stylesheet.css' do
    sass :core
end
```

With this I get the following error:

```
 myapp.rb:17 NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for "/Users/x/x/x/mysinatraapp/assets/sass":String
```

Attempt 2:

```
get '/stylesheet.css' do
    sass :'/assets/sass/core'
end
```

Attempt 3:

```
get '/stylesheet.css' do
    sass :'/assets/sass/core'
end
```

Both return the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ./views/assets/sass/core.sass
```

Attempt 4:

```
get '/stylesheet.css' do
    sass :'../assets/sass/core'
end
```

This works! however, there must be something along the lines of `set :sass, Proc.new { File.join(root, "assets/sass") }` that sets this up for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way at the moment, as Sinatra currently only accepts a single view directory.

You could try using [sinatra-compass](http://github.com/rkh/sinatra-compass#readme) and `set :compass, :sass_dir => 'assets'` and only place a single sass file  in your view folder, that will simply `@import stylesheet.sass` or you could overwrite `#sass`:

```
helpers do
  def sass(template, *args)
    template = :"#{settings.sass_dir}/#{template}" if template.is_a? Symbol
    super(template, *args)
  end
end

set :sass_dir, '../assets'
```

Comment: This answer looks great but I can't seem to get it rolling - any ideas where I am going wrong? - http://pastie.org/986956 - Thanks a lot

Comment: You use `settings.sass_dir` but `set :sass, ...`. You should `set :sass_dir, ...` (`sass` might be used by sinatra and expected to be a hash, so you should avoid using that name).

Comment: @KonstantinHaase Is this still the best/only way to do this? I am looking for a (good) method of rendering mobile layouts based on whether the client is a mobile device or not. I was hoping there was a way to change the views folder on a per route basis, like there is for the default layout.

Comment: No, you should override find_template now: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Looking%20Up%20Template%20Files

Answer (score 4):

Set your template directory then render a Sass::Engine manually.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sass'

SASS_DIR = File.expand_path("../stylesheets", __FILE__)

get "/" do
  erb :index
end

get "/stylesheets/:stylesheet.css" do |stylesheet|
  content_type "text/css"
  template = File.read(File.join(SASS_DIR, "#{stylesheet}.sass"))
  Sass::Engine.new(template).render
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this article. http://railscoder.com/setting-up-sinatra-to-use-slim-sass-and-coffeescript/

After coming across numerous sites, I was able to achieve having my sass files in a different directory instead of the 'views' directory with this article.

Answer (score 0):

I currently can't test this myself, but have you tried the following.

```
set :sass, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/assets'
```

**EDIT**: [The Sass reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#template_location-option) might help as well.

Comment: I've taken a look at the Sass ref thanks, your code snippet gives me the same error as in Attempt 1. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't help since I'm guessing you have other stuff under `views` that you want to stay put, but you can change the `views` directory as well...

```
set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/assets'
```

Then you could do:

```
get '/stylesheet.css' do
    sass :'sass/core'
end
```